# nextjs+mongodb docker deployment and running cpu is full

Tags: mongodb, docker, next.js

I have a question that has been bothering me for a long time.

Mongo's reading, writing and next-server fill up the memory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flxSa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2BDi.png)

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN npm install -g next --registry https://registry.npm.taobao.org
RUN npm install --registry https://registry.npm.taobao.org

COPY . /app

RUN npm run build

ENV MONGODB_URL "mongodb://db:27017/choiceshop"

EXPOSE 3000


# CMD echo 'Waiting for db service start...' && while ! nc -z db 27017; do sleep 1; done; echo 'Connected!' && npm run build && npm run start
CMD npm run start
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - WAIT_HOSTS=db:27017
      - WAIT_HOSTS_TIMEOUT=300
      - WAIT_SLEEP_INTERVAL=30
      - WAIT_HOST_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=30
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: 'mongo:4.4.13'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: MONGO_DATA
        target: /data/db
      - type: volume
        source: MONGO_CONFIG
        target: /data/configdb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

volumes:
  MONGO_DATA:
    name: MONGO_DATA
  MONGO_CONFIG:
    name: MONGO_CONFIG
```

project address：https://github.com/huanghanzhilian/c-shopping

Why does this happen?

After repeatedly modifying the docker configuration, I finally found that it was a problem with mongo and next-server.

Enter the logs found by the mongodb container

```
rtSecurity":259951,"after twoPhaseCommitCoordinator":269199,"after wiredTiger":1261965,"at end":1262165}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T08:40:42.581+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4615610, "ctx":"conn42","msg":"Failed to check socket connectivity","attr":{"error":"Connection reset by peer"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T08:40:42.581+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn42","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":753392}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T08:40:42.781+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"config.transactions","command":{"find":"transactions","filter":{"lastWriteDate":{"$lt":{"$date":"2024-01-20T08:09:03.215Z"}}},"projection":{"_id":1},"sort":{"_id":1},"readConcern":{},"$db":"config"},"planSummary":"EOF","keysExamined":0,"docsExamined":0,"cursorExhausted":true,"numYields":0,"nreturned":0,"reslen":108,"locks":{"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":2}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"readConcern":{"provenance":"clientSupplied"},"storage":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":32482}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T08:40:42.951+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22989,   "ctx":"conn42","msg":"Error sending response to client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Broken pipe"},"remote":"172.19.0.3:49406","connectionId":42}}
```

```
--
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:27:55.705+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:27:55.706+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:27:55.710+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:27:55.719+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:27:55.743+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:27:55.749+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:27:55.750+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReplicationDisabled","oldState":"ConfigPreStart"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:27:55.751+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:27:55.751+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:27:55.751+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:27:56.010+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20631,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost","attr":{"error":{"code":0,"codeName":"OK"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:28:01.761+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.19.0.3:53190","connectionId":1,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:28:01.786+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.19.0.3:53190","client":"conn1","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs|Mongoose","version":"5.9.1|7.6.8"},"platform":"Node.js v18.19.0, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"4.15.0-213-generic","type":"Linux"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:28:01.846+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.19.0.3:53206","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":2}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:28:01.846+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.19.0.3:53218","connectionId":3,"connectionCount":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:28:01.861+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.19.0.3:53206","client":"conn2","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs|Mongoose","version":"5.9.1|7.6.8"},"platform":"Node.js v18.19.0, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"4.15.0-213-generic","type":"Linux"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:28:01.861+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.19.0.3:53218","client":"conn3","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs|Mongoose","version":"5.9.1|7.6.8"},"platform":"Node.js v18.19.0, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"4.15.0-213-generic","type":"Linux"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:28:01.868+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.19.0.3:53222","connectionId":4,"connectionCount":4}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:28:01.869+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.19.0.3:53224","connectionId":5,"connectionCount":5}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:28:01.870+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn4","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.19.0.3:53222","client":"conn4","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs|Mongoose","version":"5.9.1|7.6.8"},"platform":"Node.js v18.19.0, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"4.15.0-213-generic","type":"Linux"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-20T13:28:01.870+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.19.0.3:53224","client":"conn5","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs|Mongoose","version":"5.9.1|7.6.8"},"platform":"Node.js v18.19.0, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"4.15.0-213-generic","type":"Linux"}}}}
--
```